# OpenShift add custom Maven repository

Tags: maven, repository, openshift

I'm using `<repository>` in the `pom.xml` file but OpenShift can not resolve dependencies, continue gets data from mavenCentral

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>MYREPOURL</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to edit your BuildConfig in Openshift and add:

```
  strategy:
    sourceStrategy:
      env:
      - name: MAVEN_MIRROR_URL
        value: http://your.local.artifactory.
```

And build again.

**Reference:**
https://blog.openshift.com/improving-build-time-java-builds-openshift/

Comment: My savior! I was struggling with this half a day now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Look for file `settings.xml` at

`${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml` or

`${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

- Create your own Maven profile.
- Specify your own repository.
- Set your profile is active.

**Reference:**

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Active_Profiles

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories